# Can't create react native app. Input is required, but expo is in non-interactive mode

Tags: react-native

I just started learning react native and I'm stuck at the beginning.
I installed react native with `npm install -g create-react-native-app`, but when i try to create app with `create-react-native-app` it just says:

> Input is required, but expo is in non-interactive mode. Required
>   input:
>   > Choose a template:

Comment: I have faced the same issue but fixed using windows powershell.

Comment: The correct way is to add the template in the end. Like `expo init test-app --template blank`

Answer (score 162):

are you using git bash? try to use normal cmd to create the project

Comment: For some reason, git bash shell on windows that I was using was not running.  Shifted to windows power shell and everything worked

Comment: That worked. But why does it not run with git bash ?

Comment: Interactive menus doesn't work under git for windows(git bash)

Comment: It's rare that somebody on the Interwebs tells me about a silly decision I made and how it doesn't work.  Thank you so much.

Comment: This was very helpful for me, as I was also trying to use Git Bash (I hate windows cmd).  Interactive mode appears to work in Cmder, though, so at least that's a little less crappy.

Answer (score 38):

you can't run the CLI in 'interactive mode' if you are using `Git Bash`, instead, you can use `cmd`, but if you insist on using `Git Bash` then you need to pass 2 arguments: `name` and `template` . so instead of

`expo init <project-name>`

you'd actually pass:

`expo init <project-name> --template <one-of-the-predefined-templates> --name <AppName>`

for example, `expo init facebook-clone --template blank --name FacebookClone`

the `template` argument defines how much boilerplate the project is initiated with 
the `name` argument defines the app name (as shown in the home screen or even in `Expo` itself)

Comment: does git bash give any other problems further along the line?

Comment: expo init facebook-clone --template blank --name FacebookClone <== no need to have this part

Answer (score 28):

Use cmd or another TTY command-line tool. Don't use git bash - it is not TTY.

```
 expo --help
 Usage: expo [options] [command]

 Options:

   -V, --version                                   output the version number
   -o, --output [format]                           Output format. pretty (default), raw
   --non-interactive                               Fail, if an interactive prompt would be required to continue. Enabled by default if stdin is not a TTY.
```

In that case you can all commands mentioned above:

```
 expo init my-new-project
```

or do expo login first

Comment: the key was to not use git bash. Up for you!

Answer (score 16):

you can use the following command.

`expo init youappfolder --template blank`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Use this command if you are using gitbash instead of cmd or powershell:

```
expo init my-app --template blank --name myApp
```

By default expo uses yarn to install packages.
If you want to use npm instead, use the following command:

```
expo init my-app --template blank --name myApp --npm
```

Answer (score 5):

you must determine what the template you neeed
so you can run this

```
expo init projectName --template blank
```

or

```
expo init projectName --template tabs
```

Answer (score 5):

Use normal `CMD(Command Prompt)` instead of using `git-bash` or some other terminals. It worked for me.

Comment: It is advisable not to start your first react-native app with `git-bash`, it is recommended you use the IDE terminal, like VScode terminal, to be precise if VScode is your code editor or any other one you prefer.
I had the same issue, but once i switched to `VScode terminal` inside the project folder, it worked

Answer (score 4):

Use cmd or another TTY command-line tool. Don't use git bash - it is not TTY.

```
expo --help
 Usage: expo [options] [command]

 Options:

   -V, --version                                   output the version number
   -o, --output [format]                           Output format. pretty (default), raw
   --non-interactive                               Fail, if an interactive prompt would
```

be required to continue. Enabled by default if stdin is not a TTY.
In that case you can all commands mentioned above:

```
expo init my-new-project
```

or do expo login first

Comment: This looks like a carbon copy of @A Ralkov's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can supply your credentials (expo website account credentials) by:

```
expo login -u YOUR-USERNAME-OR-EMAIL -p YOUR-PASSWORD
```

If you don't have one, go get one at : https://expo.io/

If you just starting learning React Native, and its necessary to run on Expo client on your mobile, you create app by:

`react-native init ptojectName`

This type of projects can run on simulator (android/ios) or on real device.

Answer (score 3):

To allow it to work in git bash, just alias the `expo` command in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` to use gitbash's `winpty`, made for just this sort of thing:

In your `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
alias expo='winpty expo.cmd '
```

Comment: Yup, I hate it everytime you have to do this in Windows. Other reminder, don't forget to restart your Git bash or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using [gitbash](https://gitforwindows.org/), like it defaults in non-interactive mode you have to specify every arguments:

```
expo init myprojectname --template blank
```

- Where "myprojectname" is the name you want to give
- template is the start options `expo init` gives which are `blank`, `tabs` or `bare-minimum`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is when you are using Git Bash, I solved it by using the in-built terminal on VS-code

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in interactive mode, then you can specify template and workflow as shown below:

expo init demoProject --template blank --workflow managed

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by

**1. Using cmd or PowerShell instead of git bash**

or

**2. Use git as an integrated terminal if you are using vscode as your text editor**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you: start again. Install expo, then run:

```
expo init my-new-project 
cd my-new-project
expo start
```

See here for details: 
https://expo.io/learn

Your life will be much easier. Then, when you gain experience, you can start playing without it.

Comment: Even if you install `expo` globally and run `expo init my-new-project`, it will fail if run within git bash. Works though with powershell, cmd or any TTY terminal.

Answer (score 0):

$ expo init --name non-interactive --template blank managed Awesome_project

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I had the same 
Issues lately but all I did was to just use my windows command prompt instead of Gitbash.